# Wildcard searching of encrypted data in a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, security, encryption, encode

I am in the process of building a small web application which will hold around 10 pieces of information for every person inserted. Due to data protection the majority of this information must be encrypted.

Using the CodeIgniter framework and the CodeIgniter encryption class I can encode the information on the application side before storing it in the database. The CodeIgniter encryption class uses PHP's mcrypt function along with the AES_256 cipher.

The problem I have is that I need to allow the users of the application to search the information stored using a wildcard search, Possibly also via an API at a later date.

Any body come across a solution for a similar problem. I've read about the MySQL AES_ENCRYPT and AES_DECRYPT but they still require passing a key back and forth in plain text which I am reluctant to do.

I am currently at the conclusion that if I wish to continue on this route then a full table decryption is my only solution every time a search is made (obviously not good).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you can't search in decrypted text without decoding it first, that is true.

However, that doesn't mean that there are no ways around this. For example, you could make an [inverted index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) of your data and hash (sha1, md5, crc32, pick one) the keys used for searching. All you have to do then is hash the search terms you're using, look them up in the index and retrieve any record that matches, which will only be a small part of the table instead of the entire thing.

By hashing the data (use a salt!), you avoid storing the data in an unsafe way, while you can still search through the data because you made an index for it. No decryption required until you're actually sure which documents match.

Comment: +1 for lateral thinking, and the use of hashing to ensure sensitive keywords are still maintained sensitively

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I think I understand what you are proposing but will the indexing still not fall short when trying to do a 'where_in' or 'like' search, for example: search %CHR% would return a record with the word CHRIS in it. Maybe i'm reading it wrong, if so could you elaborate a little please.

Comment: Correct, wildcard searches don't really work with inverted indexes, but works really well with normal searches. The only way you can do wildcard searches is to decrypt the entire thing.